# Spatial data types in MS SQL 2008 and Subsonic 3 - workaround available?

Tags: sql-server-2008, subsonic, gis

Using the latest version of Subsonic (3.0.3) it doesnt appear to me that the geometry or geography data types are implemented as of October 09.

My questions are:

- if and when is this support likely to be added?
- does anyone have a workaround to support operations on simple geography types at the DAL level?

All I really care about at this stage are storing lat/long data and performing queries over collections of coordinates (ie, find all points within 1000km radius of point X).

It would be easy enough to implement this functionality within my own code I suppose, but it would be neat to have it all supported through the DAL.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsonic is not tied to SQL Server so I dont think this is something that would ever be added. This sounds like something you can create your own extensions for.